# Typescript v4.3.5: Type guard issue - S2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

There is a guard that checks the type of http request. It worked as a library and stopped as nested code from another library.

```js
export function isTenantRequest(object: unknown): object is TenantRequest {
  return (
    !!object && // #a Check that it is not undefined nor null. -> not null
    object instanceof Object && // #b So it can contain properties. -> Object
    'tenant' in object && // #c The property exists that I am going to check -> { tenant: any } !!! maybe never
    object.tenant instanceof TenantDO && // #d Checks the instance -> -> { tenant: any }
    validateSync(object.tenant).length === 0 // #f Validates by a validator.
  );
}
```

In line #d I receive a typescript error.

```bash
error TS2339: Property 'tenant' does not exist on type 'never'.
23(#f)     validateSync(object.tenant).length === 0
```

I guess that `in` operator does not work on simple `Object` because it can not have extra properties that is why it returns never type and in the next line it fails.
I've change to the next workable variant but I do not like because of `as` operators.

```js
export function isTenantRequest(object: unknown): object is TenantRequest {
  return (
    (object as TenantRequest).tenant instanceof TenantDO &&
    validateSync((object as TenantRequest).tenant).length === 0
  );
}
```

There was advice to use

```js
 typeof x === 'object'
```

But it did not help.

Please, make me some advice to make it better.

Comment: Is `TenantRequest` a class or an interface?

Comment: When I add the supporting code and types, your function seems [to work as you expect](https://tsplay.dev/WzkJQw). Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem that has no unspecified types or functions. Otherwise we can only conclude that the problem is not in the code you've put in question.

Comment: Though going back to typescript 4.8 I see the problem. https://tsplay.dev/wQRkjN What version of typescript are you on? Relevant reading on what happening to narrowing types with `in` in Typescript 4.9 here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#in-narrowing

Comment: Yes, Main point is typescript versions. ```in``` operator works with ```4.9.5``` and stops working when it is used in a project with typescript version ```4.3.5```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript 4.3 just isn't smart enough about narrowing with the `in` operator. This was changed in [typescript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#in-narrowing)

So I don't think this is possible in version 4.3 without an `as` type assertion. But you can at least avoid any runtime crashes by being smart about where you do that assertion.

I'd probably refactor this something like:

```
class TenantDO { constructor(public tenantName: string) {} }
declare function validateSync(tenant: TenantDO): unknown[]

export function isTenantRequest(value: unknown) {
  if (!value || typeof value !== 'object') return false
  const valueAsObject = value as Record<string, unknown>
  
  return (
    'tenant' in valueAsObject &&
    valueAsObject.tenant instanceof TenantDO &&
    validateSync(valueAsObject.tenant).length === 0
  );
}
```

Now in order to get to the `value as Record<string, unknown>` line `value` *must* be an object that is capable of having properties. So you assert it to be `Record<string, unknown>` which allows you access any property, but gives no guarantee about what you get back from that property.

Then the rest of your existing code works as is to validate that property.

[See Typescript v4.3.5 Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmA7MiAuARA8tA3tYA9ohKgE4CuwqBpAFAA7kBGIAlsNKkiqgHJgBbeAC5oJUq0QBzAJS4AvtHkAoACbxQYUvGgAzcoiqsi0AG5g2qsFwDKAT0O0uyNKIQuMmGaIMBrRAQA7ogA2gC6ysrwAB70NKh6BkYmrBDuPABK8ACO5PAktOYgeT6I-kGIcjjK0NCsutC0AIRFedAAPu2cdvTwBA2tOk0AvMPQAOQETABWGqjjctqo5KSIehYQ8DX4RCRmFnkAghCYM3PQY4PQkNBZhKSqADziklIANNB+AcEAfNvbSxWa1o21qg2Op1mVAAdM4eHViKgUMA+g10mgsNAAGRY0H7SzWeD2Rzgk5nGFwtAyaEgJBSVAACwuo2gAAZtjIANzKeRAA)

---

And if you want to remove that `as` then you will most likely need to upgrade to a more recent Typescript version.